# How to automatically update a column of the second table if the same column is updated in the first table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

There is a first table M_TAX_ORG and when updating the NAME_R column, the second table M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO should also change the NAME_R column automatically. (As you can see from the screenshots, M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO is associated with M_TAX_ORG ) Are there ready-made scripts? Maybe with trigger?
[image]
[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER M_TAX_ORG_AFTER_UPDATE_1
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON M_TAX_ORG
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_NAME_R VARCHAR2(600 char);
BEGIN

    SELECT NAME_R
    INTO v_NAME_R
    FROM M_TAX_ORG WHERE TEST_USER.M_TAX_ORG.M_TAX_ORG_ID = TEST_USER.M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO.M_TAX_ORG_ID;

    UPDATE M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO ADM
    SET (ADM.NAME_R) = v_NAME_R
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT M_TAX_ORG.NAME_R
                 FROM M_TAX_ORG
                 WHERE M_TAX_ORG.M_TAX_ORG_ID = ADM.M_TAX_ORG_ID);
END;
```

I tried this script. But it's not correct.

Comment: "not correct" isn't very helpful - do get a compilation error, or runtime error, or wrong results? You should be using `:new` instead of querying the table the trigger is again, for a start. But why are you duplicating the same data in two tables anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your tables and data, and the behaviour of your current attempt it's hard to be sure; but you seem to be looking for something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER M_TAX_ORG_AFTER_UPDATE_1
    -- only fire if NAME_R was set in the update statement
    AFTER UPDATE OF NAME_R
    ON M_TAX_ORG
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO ADM
    SET ADM.NAME_R = :new.NAME_R
    WHERE ADM.M_TAX_ORG_ID = :new.M_TAX_ORG_ID;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-E3iJx-3)

This uses [the `new` pseudorecord](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E) to get the ID and name for the affected row, rather than trying to requery it; and uses those for the update of the other table.

I've also changed it to `AFTER UPDATE OF NAME_R` so it only fires if that column is affected. But note this only means it was included in update - `set NAME_R = <something>` - not that the value actually changed. You might want a condition on your update to check if the new value is actually different.

---

> how to make a script for NAME_R and NAME_K?

Add both to the `OF` clause, and set both values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER M_TAX_ORG_AFTER_UPDATE_1
    -- only fire if NAME_R or NAME_K were set in the update statement
    AFTER UPDATE OF NAME_R, NAME_K
    ON M_TAX_ORG
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO ADM
    SET ADM.NAME_R = :new.NAME_R, ADM.NAME_K = :new.NAME_K
    WHERE ADM.M_TAX_ORG_ID = :new.M_TAX_ORG_ID;
END;
```

---

Having the same data duplicated in multiple tables goes against the principles of normalisation. From the images it looks like `M_TAX_ORG_ID` should be a primary key in `M_TAX_ORG` and a foreign key in `M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO` - which may already be the case - and `NAME_R` and `NAME_K` should *only* be in `M_TAX_ORG`. You then don't need to cascade an update like this, and can just join the tables to get the name values when needed.

Comment: But I am getting this kind of error while updating table M_TAX_ORG --> ORA-04098: trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: @Amir - you query `user_errors` to see what it's failing on. I've updated the code and added a demo to my answer.

Comment: And one more question, how to make a script for NAME_R and NAME_K? I tried like this: 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER M_TAX_ORG_AFTER_UPDATE_1
    -- only fire if NAME_R was set in the update statement
    AFTER UPDATE OF NAME_R, NAME_K
    ON M_TAX_ORG
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO ADM
    SET (ADM.NAME_R, ADM.NAME_K) = (:new.NAME_R , :new.NAME_K)
    WHERE ADM.M_TAX_ORG_ID = :new.M_TAX_ORG_ID;
END;

Comment: @AmirOkay - your `set` is wrong; it should be `SET ADM.NAME_R = :new.NAME_R, ADM.NAME_K = :new.NAME_K`.